# Error in code based off negative numbers. Need possible fix on time calculator. Need help on where i should add the additional minutes of the day

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, math

Hi I have created a program in C++, (which I am very new too). This program basically asks the used for two times such as 3:57 and the duration 1:05 and it will tell you the sum and the difference between the two. The problem is I am getting negative remainders such as if I put an input of 1:18 and 10:39 I expect 11:57 and 2:39 but I get 11:57 and -9:-21 as result when I run the program. What should I do? This is for an assignment and we cannot use if statements. The instructions say if we are having this problem we should " This is easily done by adding a day (or two or three) to before when calculating the difference." I do not know what this means and have been struggling on this. i pass most tests besides when the time goes negative code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int run()
{




    cout << "Give me a time (such as 3:57) and a duration" << endl;
    cout << "(such  1:05), and  will tell you the sum" << endl;
    cout << "(that is the time that follows the given time" << endl;
    cout << "by the given duration), and difference (the time that proceeds the given time by that duration)."  << endl;

    cout << "Time: " << endl;
    int timeHours;
    int timeMinutes;
    char discard;

    cin >>  timeHours >> discard >> timeMinutes;


    cout <<"Duration: " << endl;
    int durationHours;
    int durationMinutes;

    cin >> durationHours >> discard >> durationMinutes;



int time = timeHours * 60 + timeMinutes;
 int duration = durationHours * 60 + durationMinutes;
 int after = time + duration;
 int before = time - duration ;
 int afterHours = after / 60 % 12  ;
 int afterMinutes = after % 60;
 int beforeHours = before  / 60 ;
 int beforeMinutes = before % 60;



cout << endl;
 cout << durationHours <<":" << durationMinutes << " hours after and before, "
 << timeHours << ":"  <<timeMinutes << " is ["  << afterHours   << ":" << setw(2) << 
setfill('0')<< afterMinutes <<", "
 << beforeHours << ":" << beforeMinutes << "]" << endl;
return(0);
}
```

Any help to make this program work properly is greatly appreciated. I am new to C++ and very frustrated.

Comment: A debugger + a breakpoint on the single `cout << endl;` line in this code, followed by some variable inspection on all of those calculated values, will probably be *highly* informative. Consider this: given the input you've stated, `time` will be 1*60 + 18 (e.g. 78), and duration will be 10*60 + 39 (e.g. 639). So why would you be surprised that `before`, which is `time - duration`, would be a negative number, as would `beforeHours` and `beforeMinutes` (both of which are based on `before`).

Comment: There are specific rules to how modulo works with negative values. I can honestly never remember them, because they can vary across languages/architectures. A simple solution is to first check if the time is negative before splitting it into components. Then negate it so you're dealing with positive values again, and record the fact that you did this. You can reapply the negative later.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i have edited it and included all things if you can possibly help now.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am still very confused. I understand what I did wrong but how should I fix it?

Comment: @paddy how should i go about doing this?

Comment: Just one bit of advice, when working with time use `#include <chrono>`. Time logic has more loopholes then you know.

Comment: @PepijnKramer i am doing this for an assignment. I don't think i am able to use that library. and even if i could i don't think i would know what to do> Any advice on how I can fix this?

Comment: You're not allowing for the clock rolling over.   So you expect the difference between 1:18 and 10:39 to treat the 1:18 as if it is actually 13:18.

Comment: @Peter so how do i fix this is what im asking. I know this is the problem but how do i solve it.

Comment: Use the absolute difference (always positive)

Comment: @PepijnKramer how do i do that?

Comment: Use an if statement

Comment: @PepijnKramer in this assignment we are not allowed to use if-else statements. it says if we have the problem i'm having : "This is easily done by adding a day (or two or three) to "before" when calculating the difference." I do not know what they mean by this.

Comment: "add a day" = "add the number of minutes in a day"

Comment: @paddy  I did this added 1440 (minutes in a day) and it gave me even more errors. i added it to int before = 1440 + time - hours

Comment: what I should ask is where should I add that too?? @paddy

Comment: What errors specifically? It will of course make your times have lots of hours. But as you already know, you can deal with that via the modulo operator just like you're doing with minutes already.

Comment: right after: `int before = time - duration ;` insert: `after%=1440; if (after<0) after+=1440; before%=1440; if (before<0) before+=1440;` that should overcome the problems `paddy`  is describing in his first comment

Comment: @paddy what i am asking is where do i add those 1440 minutes. I am running it through a tester and many tests are coming back negative. I am asking where do I add the extra "day" (the 1440 minutes) to make this program work? do i add it in "int before"? if so when i do that does not work. I do not know how to fix this issue

Comment: It's gotten to the point where you need to sit down with a pen and paper, write out some values and figure out what steps you must follow to get from what you have to the answer you need using only the operations you're allowed to use. Just pretend you're a computer, doing what you're told. Once you've worked it out, either forwards or backwards or both, then formulate that procedure into code. Beyond this, there's little more we can do to help, except solve your assignment for you. But then you'll miss out on the most crucial part of leaning to code: experience = problem-solving + pain.

Comment: @paddy ended up solving it. Thanks. I'm new to C++. Previously I mostly did front end web work.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
 int after = time + duration;
 if(time - duration < 0) time += 1440;
 int before = time - duration;
 int afterHours = after / 60 % 12;
```

P.s. Sorry about non-intuitive code block, I'm new around here.